# pthread_create is called multiple times while the previous thread with same routine is running

Tags: c, pthreads

Is there any memory leaked or any other problem in second `pthread_create` call (e.g: memory allocated for pthread) if I accidentally call to `pthread_create` twice while the previous thread with same routine is running?

```
static void* thread_routine(void *data)
{
   while (1) {sleep(1)}
   return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    static pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_routine, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_routine, NULL);

    while (1) {//> never return <//}
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks for your helps/answers.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think the question is duplicated. The query here in this question is not about thread safe, but other problems especially memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There's no memory leak. You are fine to call the same thread function multiple times and it's also fine to reuse the same thread identifier (`thread_id`). But note, you can't *join* with a thread without its ID. In fact, it's one of the common use-cases of threads: a large work is split into small, identical chunks and multiple threads work on them.

By the way, you don't need to have a infinite loop in main thread. If you don't need the main thread, then simply call [`pthread_exit(0);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) from `main()`.
The busy-wait loop is simply wasting CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It is good not know. Thanks.